# MySQL InnoDB performance issues

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have the following DB structure on my MySQL 5.1.66:

```
ID         int(11) PRIMARY
CID        varchar(255) INDEX
V1         varchar(1500)
DATE       datetime
IP_ADDR    varchar(255)
V2         varchar(1000)
USER_DELAY int(11)
M_ID       int(22)
REFERER    varchar(255)
BRAND      varchar(255)
LANG       varchar(255)
USER       varchar(255)
```

I have almost 9,000,000 rows in the DB and here are some of my more important my.cnf properties:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
key_buffer_size = 128M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 128M
max_heap_table_size = 128M
sort_buffer_size = 8M
tmp_table_size = 128M
```

The problem is, when running a simple query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CID = 123456
```

It takes over 60 seconds to get a response (CID is an indexed field and the query has only 10 results).

EXPLAIN output for the above query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table | ALL  | CID           | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 9193357 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

**EDIT**:
I just noticed something, when I place the value under quotes, I get the results in 0.13 seconds, but if I run the query without the quotes it takes 60 seconds, what causes this?

Comment: Show us the complete indexes as well as an `EXPLAIN` of your statement.

Comment: @njk please see my last edit for the ``EXPLAIN`` My only INDEX is the ``CID`` and my PRIMARY is ``ID``.

Comment: I think 60 sec. is so many. Try rebuild index.

Comment: How many rows returns query? Also can helped if you show index statistics.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan please see my last edit

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM table WHERE CID='123456'`.  You're comparing a string field with an integer.

Comment: @JoshuaMartell Yes I've noticed the difference in performance (see my last edit) - why is this happening? I understand I need to use quotes but I was under the impression I will get an error back if I'm trying to compare varchar to int instead of getting slow results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you place the value under quotes server will use index if there are no quotes i.e. integer value passed in WHERE clause and index won't works.
You think `123456` will be converts to `varchar` and then index must works. No. **The precedence of `integer` higher than `varchar`** then all `CID` values will  be converted to `integer` to compare and you have table scan.

Answer (score 0):

The type of CID is important. If you want to use the index correctly, you should build the query with the correct type In your case, CID is varchar. Therefore it is expected that you give a value in quotes. Otherwise it will be converted into integer which takes lots of time.